# Is this a standard alignment issue or something else?

Tags: tires, steering, alignment, steering-wheel

I am working on a vehicle that travels a little to the right when the steering wheel is not held in the centered position.  But when the steering wheel is held in the centered position, the vehicle travels straight.

Is this a standard alignment issue or is something else going on?

Comment: This could be due to the crown in the road. The slant will cause the vehicle to track in that direction. Hard to find an "exactly level" road, so don't know how to test this theory on the highway.

Comment: are your tires wearing in strange ways?

Comment: @CcDd Great question.  Tire wear looks normal.

Comment: Whenever I get one that pulls or drifts the first I do is swap the front tires side for side and retest. If the pull changes sides then we assume the tires are causing the problem.

Comment: What is the steering wheel's "natural" position when you're driving the vehicle? Is it centered or do you need to pull it back to center. You can test @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2's theory by driving on the left side of a divided highway or one-way street. If it is due to the crown the drift should now be to the left. If the steering wheel is off, it could be that the toe-in adjustment is a bit off, or if the wheel is centered, you might have too much negative camber on the left front. If the pull is minor it might take quite a while to show up in the tires.